# unable to retrieve date from mysql into JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

the issue that i have at the moment is i cannot retrieve a date object from my mysql database, so far no matter what i try, i either get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

or

```
java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date
```

does anyone have an idea regarding what can be done to solve this.

i have tried [this](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/mysql-date-java.shtml) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/385771/java/java/java-sql-Date-dd-mm) but i still come to the same two errors which are both caused by the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'0000-00-00' is an invalid date.  It should not exist in your data.

Therefore, you need to either:

1. clean up the data and turn off allow_invalid_dates in your MySQL configuration (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates)
2. write java code to catch the date exceptions and deal with the bad data
3. write SQL to substitute a default date for invalid date, as suggested by John Woo.

The problem with 3 is that there are other invalid dates (e.g. '2012-02-31') that might throw exceptions also.  Good luck.

Comment: the data should never be invalid, although the test data i had used was forcing it to use the default date

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the others have answered (including the **very** good advice that storing invalid dates is not a good idea) you can also instruct the JDBC driver to handle those invalid dates differently:

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading.html

> Connector/J 3.1 throws an exception by default when these values are encountered as this is the most correct behavior according to the JDBC and SQL standards. This behavior can be modified using the zeroDateTimeBehavior configuration property. The permissible values are:
>   -  **exception** (the default), which throws an SQLException with an SQLState of S1009.
>   -  **convertToNull**, which returns NULL instead of the date.
>   -  **round**, which rounds the date to the nearest closest value which is 0001-01-01.

I would recommend to use `convertToNull`

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for a description on how to specify configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

if you are retrieving rows from the database, format the dates in your `select` statement,

```
SELECT if(colDate = '0000-00-00', curdate(), colDate), ....
```

just replace `CURDATE()` to your desired default date. The reason why the exception arises is because `0000-00-00` is not a valid date.